# Break Lines in Crystal Report Asp.Net on next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report file with grouping to separate each record per group. I have a problem with the line representing column there are scenarios where the page is on the next page, the line extends downward all the way down to the bottom

[image]

Comment: where is the error? where is the second page? what do you need in page2

Comment: Were you not able to view the image?

Comment: I can see the image but couldn't see any error over there.

Comment: the error is that the line is over extending downward where it should stop before the red horizontal line

Comment: In which section have you draw the lines? and where did you place headings and data.. basically I need the section names.

Comment: Hi @Silva , In Report Header, I have there the Name of the group as page header, also the COLUMN NAMES / COLUMN HEADER of the table, after that is the group header section then Section Details after that is the body of the table. I think I found out the problem, I am extending the vertical column line from the table column names/ header upto the body that is why when the data is broken and needed to extend to second page, the lines extended all the way down. as Solution, I separate the column line from the header to the body of the table

Comment: yes that is the problem tou are extending the lines toomuch to other sections.. just limit the lines to only that section then you don't get any errors.

Comment: another problem concerning lines, @Silva, when I tried to export the report in Excel, the lines borders is lost. Is there anything to do for those to be retained?

Comment: Normally to my experience... do go to excel export with formattting instead just export data.. coming to your problem I don't have much idea on that.